# Pycharm Pong game

Tags: pycharm

So I'm making a pong game in Pycharm, and I'm trying to display the ball onto the screen but I keep getting a "This code is unreachable" error and I have no clue what to do. I am getting the error right where it says paddle_a = turtle.Turtle(). Could someone please help.

```
    #Simple pong game
#3.12.19
# Connor

import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong by Connork.")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)


# Main-game-loop
while True:
    wn.update()
# Paddle-A

paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)



# Paddle B



# Ball
```

Comment: You have an endless `while True` loop, execution won't reach `# Paddle-A`.

Comment: Generally, the `tracer()` and `update()` methods are used to fine tune the performance of a working program -- you really shouldn't start out with them, it just leads to trouble.